# Cambiar estilo de Autocompletar Chrome

Tags: angular, chrome, input, autocompletar

Estoy usando Angular material para mi página web y al centrar el texto de los input me sigue apareciendo la ventana de autocompletar a la izquierda. Me pregunto si hay alguna forma de poder centrar la ventana de autocompletar de chrome o al menos que ocupe todo el ancho del input.

Adjunto imagen de como aparece el autocompletar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez lo que buscas es [`-webkit-autofill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill). Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, he estado mirando el -webkit-autofill y por lo que he visto solo afecta al input cuando está siendo rellenado y no al estilo que tiene el autofill, no sé si se me ha escapado algún detalle.